# Why am I seeing large gaps between requests in Chrome’s Network Waterfall feature?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, google-chrome-devtools

I’m trying to get to the bottom of a slow load time for a site. I’m currently using Chrome’s Network Waterfall visual, and I’m seeing a few long gaps between a request being fulfilled and the next one starting. I don’t know if this is something very specific to my project that I need to try and track down in the code, or if there is a general reason why this might be happening. Something I should look for.

Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

You can ignore the grey line in the center of the second image. That’s just a hot reloader for my webpack/react project.

Answer (score 0):

Try profiling in "Performance" tab. You'll find that javascript code is parsed and executed during that time period.